# Laugh detection in Android

Tags: applications, camera, microphone, front-camera

I'm trying to detect laughs in Android. Something like a score if your laugh is louder or something similar.

Is it possible to detect laughs maybe through microphone, or facial detection through cameras? Any libraries/APIs or ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Sources of facial detection, on a phone that detects face rests at:

```
/system/vendor/pittpatt/models
/system/vendor/pittpatt/recognition
```

I'm using CM13 for my case. They are located there. Maybe facial detection might do that

Comment: Is that online resource? What is the http address?

Comment: Do you mean `https://github.com/opengapps/all/tree/master/vendor/pittpatt/models`?

Comment: No in file system of a recognition supported phone that's where the files rest. If you can point out to a web source that has the source for the binaries, you'll actually get what you want at the initial. I think the one at recognition are the ones responsible for detection